# No error during debug but error during normal execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a multi-threading program and at times i received segmentation fault. Hence, in order to effectively debug this fault, i would make use of the `gdb` function.

Usually, i would write all my object file in the a shell script file as followed.

`g++  ObjectFile.o ObjectFile2.o LogicFile.cpp -lpthread LogicExe`

In order to debug, i just added a `-g` extension behind.

`g++  ObjectFile.o ObjectFile2.o LogicFile.cpp -lpthread LogicExe -g`

Next, i would use this command `gdb LogicExe`, followed by `run LogicExe`.

In spite of running multiple times, there's no segmentation fault at all while it happens otherwise when i compile without the `gdb` and `-g` function.

Why does the debugger not detect the segmentation fault like the normal execution would?

Comment: My crystal ball says you probably have a race condition somewhere and the debugger changes the timing between threads enough that it no longer causes trouble (as often). But it's impossible to know without seeing the code. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) in your question.

Comment: When you change two things at once it's sometimes hard to tell which caused the problem. Can you try this: Does the version compiled without `-g` fail or work correctly when run with gdb?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick when i compile without the `-g` , the segmentation fault will occur at times, however when i run in `-g` and `gdb` format, the segmentation fault will never occur despite how many times i run them.

Comment: OK. One thing gdb does is disable address space randomization. This provides a consistent environment every time you debug the program, but as you saw it can mask certain errors. Type `set disable-randomization off ` to gdb before `run`, and your program should run as it normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a program under gdb, the execution will differ in a few ways compared to running it directly from a shell:

- gdb will, by default, [disable Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR)](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#index-set-disable_002drandomization-122) in order to give you more reproducible results on each run. But this may mask memory corruption errors in your program. You can disable this feature by typing `(gdb) set disable-randomization off` before starting your program.
- gdb will set `LINES` and `COLUMNS` in your program's environment, creating them if they were not present. This will alter the size of the environment, thus the base of the stack of the program will be different when run under gdb. You can remove those variables from the environment by typing `(gdb) unset environment COLUMNS` and `(gdb) unset environment LINES` before starting your program.
- gdb monitors dynamic library events and thread creation, briefly stopping execution when they occur.